# IOS Notification Permission alert does not show

Tags: ios, react-native, apple-push-notifications, expo

SDK Version: 39.0.0
Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): All
I am not getting accept or decline notifications permissions alert when loading my app in production.

I have tried clearing certificates and keys and allowing expo to add everything from a clean slate, but still no luck. I am starting to think maybe it’s my code which is the reason why the alert doesn’t get fired.

```
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
import { Permissions } from "expo-permissions";
import { Notifications as Notifications2 } from "expo";

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: true,
    shouldSetBadge: false
  })
});

export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    notification: {},
    errorMessage: null
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
    //Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(this._handleNotification);
    Notifications2.addListener(data => {
      this.setState({ notification: data });
    });

    Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(
      this._handleNotificationResponse
    );
  }

  _handleNotification = notification => {
    this.setState({ notification: notification });
  };

  _handleNotificationResponse = response => {
    console.log(response);
  };

  handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const { email, password } = this.state;

      const expoPushToken = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();

      console.log(expoPushToken);

      const userinfo = await firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      console.log("user ID ", userinfo.user.uid);

      await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .doc(userinfo.user.uid.toString())
        .update({
          expo_token: expoPushToken["data"]
        })
        .then(function() {
          console.log("token successfully updated!");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          // The document probably doesn't exist.
          console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("=======Error in login", error);
      this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message });
    }
  };


  registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async () => {
    if (Constants.isDevice) {
      const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
        Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
      );
      let finalStatus = existingStatus;
      if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
        const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(
          Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
        );
        finalStatus = status;
      }
      if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
        alert("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
        return;
      }
      const token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
      console.log(token);
      //this.setState({ expoPushToken: token });
    } else {
      alert("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
    }

    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
        name: "default",
        importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
        vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
        lightColor: "#FF231F7C"
      });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

import { Permissions } from "expo-permissions";

should of been

import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

Sometimes we all make simple mistakes.